# Loop with different value through HTTP-Get-Request in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

PROBLEM FIXED

```
source:Protocols[] = [];

var lengthArray = 6
var arrayid = [2, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i <= lengthArray-1; i++) {
    let urlstring: string = '.../display/'  + arrayid[i]    + '/protocols';

  this.httpClient.get<Protocols[]>(urlstring)
  .subscribe(protocols => {
    for (const item of protocols) {
      this.source.push({Id: item['Id']});
    }
    console.log(arrayid[i], this.source);
----->        this.source = []
  });
}
```

I want to loop through a url with the use of a http-get-request to get different responses depending on the arrayid.
My problem is that the responses overlap and are not the same like in postman.
My assumption is, that the values in "this.source" continous and are not reset.
Any tips to solve the problem?

Thanks!

```
source:Protocols[] = [];

var lengthArray = 6
var arrayid = [2, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i <= lengthArray-1; i++) {
    let urlstring: string = '.../display/'  + arrayid[i]    + '/protocols';

  this.httpClient.get<Protocols[]>(urlstring)
  .subscribe(protocols => {
    for (const item of protocols) {
      this.source.push({Id: item['Id']});
    }
    console.log(arrayid[i], this.source);
  });
}
```

for every array value(2, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5) i receive:

```
0: {Id: 13}
1: {Id: 14}
2: {Id: 15}
3: {Id: 19}
4: {Id: 20}
5: {Id: 21}
6: {Id: 28}
7: {Id: 28}
8: {Id: 29}
9: {Id: 29}
.....
length: 169
```

When i delete the for loop and change the arrayid number manually the values are right like in postman:

for array value 2 :

```
0: {Id: 155}
1: {Id: 156}
2: {Id: 157}
3: {Id: 154}
length: 4
```

for array value 6 :

```
empty because there is no value
length: 0
```

for array value 1 :

```
0: {Id: 13}
1: {Id: 14}
2: {Id: 15}
3: {Id: 19}
4: {Id: 20}
5: {Id: 21}
6: {Id: 28}
7: {Id: 28}
8: {Id: 29}
9: {Id: 29}
.....
length: 162
```

for array value 3 :

```
empty because there is no value
length: 0
```

for array value 4 :

```
empty because there is no value
length: 0
```

for array value 5 :

```
0: {Id: 158}
1: {Id: 159}
2: {Id: 174}
length: 3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "My problem is that the responses overlap and are not the same like in postman"? Can you give some examples of what you want to achieve? I don't know how the result in PostMan nor your code snippet is. Is the problem that `source` is being empty after each request?

Comment: i update my post! thank you

Comment: I am guessing that the result is the same, but the order is different? If you look at the full list of results, you should end up having the same ids, but the order may vary depending on when the request are resolved. Is that right? Or do you end up with the same list 6 times? Can you check the Newtork tab in your browser to see the outgoing requests?

Comment: I end up with the same list 6 times. I think for some reason, the array from is not clearing after one for loop iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there's something else going one other places in your code. Are you able to replace the small snippet you created with the actual Angular code you have written (I assume it's angular since you tagged the question with `angular`)? Or even better, provide a StackBlitz example?